# How can I change order of list items using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to order some li based on their ids.

Currently I have:

```
<ul bx-slider="" id="rotator" style="width: auto; position: relative;">

    <li class="promo-banner ng-scope" ng-repeat="feature in events | limitTo:2" 
          bx-slider-item="" ordering="" id="ORDER-ROTATOR2"
          style="float: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; width: 1510px; z-index: 50; display: block;">
    </li>

    <li class="promo-banner ng-scope" ng-repeat="feature in events | limitTo:2"
        bx-slider-item="" id="ORDER-ROTATOR1" ordering=""
        style="float: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; width: 1510px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
    </li>

</ul>
```

and my directive is:

```
.directive('ordering', function () {

    var linker2 = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var elem = angular.element('#rotator').find('li').sort(sortMe);
        console.log(elem);
        angular.element('#rotator').append(elem);

        function sortMe(a, b) {
            return a.id < b.id;
        }

    };

    return {
        link: linker2
    }
})
```

it looks like it sorting but not on their ids.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use the orderBy pipe?

Comment: can I use orderby to order by className or id?

Comment: yes, the docs on it are extensive, it's native to angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderby filter with angularjs

To have multiple parameters,

```
 <li class="promo-banner ng-scope" ng-repeat="feature in events | limitTo:2 | orderBy:['className','id']" bx-slider-item="" ordering="" id="ORDER-ROTATOR2" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; width: 1510px; z-index: 50; display: block;"></li>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. Please also note that the list item is getting its id by using a directive. Maybe when the orderBy comes up, the li hasn't got it's id already?

Comment: did you try with 1?

Comment: do you mean if tried only with id or only with class? yes I did

Comment: something issue with your code then, try to do only with orderby by removing limitTo

Comment: strange, you need to provide your code as plunker or in fiddle